# jQuery scrips are conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The script consists of 3 "blocks" as I call it. Block 1 is the Menu part. Block 2, the slider and Block 3 the photos. I have tried to put these blocks in a different sequence. In all cases, the Menu block works ok.

If I put the slider block above the photos, the slider is not working anymore. If I put the photos above the slider, then the photos are not working anymore.

Here is the script I have. It is generated by 3 software programs generating the menu, slider, and photo blocks and I have put this in the head section of the webpage. How can I solve this?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css;">

    <!-----menu block---->

    <!-- Start css3menu.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS3 Menu.css3prj_files/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>
    <!-- End css3menu.com HEAD section -->

    <!-----slider block---->

    <!-- Insert to your webpage before the </head> -->
    <script src="sliderengine/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sliderengine/amazingslider-1.css">
    <script src="sliderengine/initslider-1.js"></script>
    <!-- End of head section HTML codes -->

    <!-- Insert to your webpage before the </head> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sliderengine/amazingslider-2.css">
    <script src="sliderengine/initslider-2.js"></script>
    <!-- End of head section HTML codes -->


    <!-- Insert to your webpage before the </head> -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sliderengine/amazingslider-3.css">
    <script src="sliderengine/initslider-3.js"></script>
    <!-- End of head section HTML codes -->

    <!-- Insert to your webpage before the </head> -->
    <script src="sliderengine2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="sliderengine2/amazingslider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sliderengine2/amazingslider-1.css">
    <script src="sliderengine2/initslider-1.js"></script>
    <!-- End of head section HTML codes -->

    <!-----pphoto block---->

    <!-- algemeen-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="algemeen01, VisualLightBox, LightBox, Photo Gallery, jQuery Lightbox, Javascript Gallery" />
    <meta name="description" content="algemeen01 created with VisualLightBox, a free wizard program that helps you easily generate beautiful Lightbox-style web photo galleries" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_algemeen_files/vlb_files3/vlightbox3.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_algemeen_files/vlb_files3/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="index_algemeen_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="index_algemeen_files/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->

    <!-- kerst03-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="kerst03, VisualLightBox, LightBox, Photo Gallery, lightbox flash gallery, lightbox js web gallery generator" />
    <meta name="description" content="kerst03 created with VisualLightBox, a free wizard program that helps you easily generate beautiful Lightbox-style web photo galleries" />
            <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_kerst_files/vlb_files1/vlightbox1.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_kerst_files/vlb_files1/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="index_kerst_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="index_kerst_files/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->

    <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_herfst_files/vlb_files2/vlightbox2.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_herfst_files/vlb_files2/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="index_herfst_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="index_herfst_files/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->



    <!-- Start VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_VP2017_files/vlb_files4/vlightbox4.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_VP2017_files/vlb_files4/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="index_VP2017_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="index_VP2017_files/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End VisualLightBox.com HEAD section -->


    <meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="RevealTrans( Duration=4,Transition=12 )">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index3000_g.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection,print">  <!--// Document Style //-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_p.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection,print">  <!--// Page Style //-->
    <script src="index3000_g.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       <!--// Document Script //-->
</head>
```

Comment: Well I can see you have included JQuery 5 times, so thats probably part of the issue.

Check your console and see what errors you are getting.

Comment: Include your scripts at the bottom of your page. You shouldn't need to have `-1`, `-2`, etc files. You should be able to have one set of code run multiple instances with a small config for each instance.